# How to embed latest tweets in Sitecore 6.5

Tags: sitecore

I have to embed latest tweets in a Sitecore 6.5 project as given below image

[image]

How can I implement this functionality.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: looks like homework to me

Comment: Sitecore homework? Really? I would love some of that! hahaha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as you would add it into any website... create a component for it and use the twitter API like this for example: http://jsfiddle.net/abenlumley/xRwam/4/

```
/*********************************************************************
  #### Twitter Post Fetcher! ####
  Coded by Jason Mayes 2013.
  www.jasonmayes.com
  Please keep this disclaimer with my code if you use it. Thanks. :-)
  Got feedback or questions, ask here: http://goo.gl/JinwJ

  Ammended by Ben Lumley and djb31st 2013
  www.dijitul.com
  Ammended to display latest tweet only with links
********************************************************************/
var twitterFetcher=function(){var d=null;return{fetch:function(a,b){d=b;var c=document.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://cdn.syndication.twimg.com/widgets/timelines/"+a+"?&lang=en&callback=twitterFetcher.callback&suppress_response_codes=true&rnd="+Math.random();document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(c)},callback:function(a){var b=document.createElement("div");b.innerHTML=a.body;a=b.getElementsByClassName("e-entry-title");d(a)}}}();

/*
* ### HOW TO USE: ###
* Create an ID:
* Go to www.twitter.com and sign in as normal, go to your settings page.
* Go to "Widgets" on the left hand side.
* Create a new widget for "user timeline". Feel free to check "exclude replies"
* if you dont want replies in results.
* Now go back to settings page, and then go back to widgets page, you should
* see the widget you just created. Click edit.
* Now look at the URL in your web browser, you will see a long number like this:
* 345735908357048478
* Use this as your ID below instead!
*/

twitterFetcher.fetch('345190342812909568', function(tweets){
  // Do what you want with your tweets here! For example:
  var x = tweets.length;
  var n = 0;
  var element = document.getElementById('tweets');
  var html = '<ul>';
    if (tweets[n].innerHTML) {
      html += '<li>' + tweets[n].innerHTML + '</li>';
    } else {
      html += '<li>' + tweets[n].textContent + '</li>';
    }
    n++;
  html += '</ul>';
  element.innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: thanks for reply...but here I'm getting only text.I have to display `date` also...How to get `date` for particular tweet...

Comment: @Sukhi Look at https://dev.twitter.com/docs there you can find all information regarding using twitter APIs.

Comment: this sample use hashtags to fetch latest tweet but how can I fetch tweet by username?

Answer (score 2):

Hello You can do this See below code. I am pasting code here for a single sublayout. Please update some tokens as per your requirement. This code will return you a Json you can get that json in JQuery.

Code - ----------------

public partial class LatestTweets : BaseSublayout
    {
        SiteItem objSiteItem = SiteItem.GetSiteRoot();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (objSiteItem != null)
            {
                hdJsonData.Value = GetTweets();
                frLatestTweets.Item = objSiteItem;
                frLatestTweets.Item = objSiteItem;
                frFollowUsLink.Item = objSiteItem;
                ltFollowUs.Text = Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text(Constants.FOLLOW_US);
                ltTweetUs.Text = Sitecore.Globalization.Translate.Text(Constants.TWEET_US);
            }
        }

```
    public string GetTweets()
    {

        // oauth application keys
        var oauth_token = objSiteItem.AccessToken.Rendered;
        var oauth_token_secret = objSiteItem.AccessTokenSecret.Rendered;
        var oauth_consumer_key = objSiteItem.ConsumerKey.Rendered;
        var oauth_consumer_secret = objSiteItem.ConsumerSecret.Rendered;
        var screen_name = objSiteItem.TwitterUser.Rendered;
        // oauth implementation details
        var oauth_version = "1.0";
        var oauth_signature_method = "HMAC-SHA1";

        // unique request details
        var oauth_nonce = Convert.ToBase64String(
            new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes(DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()));

        var timeSpan = DateTime.UtcNow
            - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

        var oauth_timestamp = Convert.ToInt64(timeSpan.TotalSeconds).ToString();

        // message api details
        var status = "Updating status via REST API if this works";

        var resource_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json";

        // create oauth signature
        var baseFormat = "oauth_consumer_key={0}&oauth_nonce={1}&oauth_signature_method={2}" +
                        "&oauth_timestamp={3}&oauth_token={4}&oauth_version={5}&screen_name={6}";

        var baseString = string.Format(baseFormat,
                                        oauth_consumer_key,
                                        oauth_nonce,
                                        oauth_signature_method,
                                        oauth_timestamp,
                                        oauth_token,
                                        oauth_version,
                                        Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name)
                                    );

        baseString = string.Concat("GET&", Uri.EscapeDataString(resource_url), "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(baseString));

        var compositeKey = string.Concat(Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret),
                                "&", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token_secret));

        string oauth_signature;

        using (HMACSHA1 hasher = new HMACSHA1(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(compositeKey)))
        {
            oauth_signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hasher.ComputeHash(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(baseString)));
        }

        // create the request header
        var headerFormat = "OAuth oauth_nonce=\"{0}\", oauth_signature_method=\"{1}\", " +
                           "oauth_timestamp=\"{2}\", oauth_consumer_key=\"{3}\", " +
                           "oauth_token=\"{4}\", oauth_signature=\"{5}\", " +
                           "oauth_version=\"{6}\"";

        var authHeader = string.Format(headerFormat,
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_nonce),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature_method),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_timestamp),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_token),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_signature),
                                Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_version)
                        );

        // make the request
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        var postBody = "screen_name=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(screen_name);//
        resource_url += "?" + postBody;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resource_url);
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
        return responseData;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply...this is also helpful if we implement this in code behind...

Answer (score 0):

As @IvanL said, you will simply want to create a sublayout and add the markup/JS/etc as you normally would. Below, I describe an easy-to-use library that will help you to get your Tweets via Twitter's API and also a jQuery plugin that will help simplify the way you render them. All you would need to do is wire up the library, make the necessary C# call, and then use the jQuery plugin to help you render the Tweets, using the markup style that you specify.

As mentioned below, note that I originally wrote both the library and the jQuery plugin for integration with a Sitecore 6.5 environment, and made them flexible enough to use with any solution.

**Getting and Rendering Tweets**

I created a C# library for the Twitter API about a year ago, named [TweetNET](http://zkniebel.github.io/TweetNet/). It has MSDN style documentation, and I built it in such a way as it could be integrated into .NET applications, and the first production site that I used it on was a Sitecore 6.5 site. The documentation and examples are pretty comprehensive, but if you have any questions, feel free to let me know.

As for the actual displaying of the Tweets after getting them from Twitter, I also have another repo, [Twitter Feed](http://zkniebel.github.io/jquery-twitter-feed/), which is a jQuery plugin designed to simplify rendering Tweets. Both projects include examples of the TweetNET's use, and the Twitter Feed project also includes examples of its call, so this would be a one-stop-shop for you.

**TweetNET - Latest Tweets Call**

TweetNET reduces the code that you need in order to get the latest Tweets for a given handle to the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using TweetNET.OAuth;
using TweetNET.Requests.Timelines.Statuses;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var consumerKey = "your consumerKey";
        var consumerSecret = "your consumerSecret";
        var oAuthToken = "your oAuthToken";
        var oAuthTokenSecret = "your oAuthTokenSecret";

        var twitterHandle = "your twitter handle";

        var tokens = new SecurityTokens(consumerKey, consumerSecret, oAuthToken, oAuthTokenSecret);

        var utGETRequest = new UserTimelineRequest(tokens);
        utGETRequest.Screen_Name = twitterHandle;

        var request = utGETRequest.BuildRequest();
        WebResponse response = utGETRequest.SendRequest(request);
        string responseData = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

**Twitter Feed - Rendering Tweets**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#feedTarget").twitterFeed({
                count: 4,
                rawData: yourRawJSONData,
                prepend: "<div class='tweetWrapper'>", 
                append: "</div>",
                tweetBodyClass: "tweetBody tweetText",
                date: { prepend: "<div>", append: " - ", order: 3, cssClass: "tweetDate" },
                retweet: { show: false },
                favorite: { prepend: " - ", order: 0, append: "</div>" },
                callbackOnEach: true,
                callback: function() { 
                $(this).find(".tweetBody").myCallbackOnEachTweet(); 
            }
          });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get latest tweet read following url

```
https://umerpasha.wordpress.com/2013/06/13/c-code-to-get-latest-tweets-using-twitter-api-1-1/
```